# How to integrate $\int s/(s^2+1)^{0.5}\,ds$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate  $\int s/(s^2+1)^{0.5}\,ds$? the substitution for $s^2=x$ doesn't provide the solution : $(s^2+1)^{0.5}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

First, we can write your integral as the equivalent $\int s(s^2 + 1)^{-1/2}\,ds$

For substituting, $$\text{ Choose }\;x = s^2 + 1\implies dx = 2s \,ds \iff \frac 12 dx = s\,ds$$

This will give you a very nice integral where you'll need only the power rule.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Using for example the Chain Rule, prove that

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx=2\sqrt{f(x)}+C$$

And now just observe that

$$s=\frac12\left(s^2+1\right)'\ldots$$